# Angular 2/ CLI Refresh Browser after update

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Using Angular 5.2.2 and Angular CLI 1.7.0. After `ng build --prod` and updating the server. The clients are still on the old version and are not able to see updated version. Even with the hashed bundles. Is there a way to auto update to the latest without having to have the client click refresh button on browser (basically force an refresh for them)? Thank you in advance.

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.0
Node: 8.9.4
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.2.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router, service-worker

@angular/cdk: 5.2.0
@angular/cli: 1.7.0
@angular/material: 5.2.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.1
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.1
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.1
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.0
@schematics/angular: 0.3.1
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.1
typescript: 2.7.1
webpack: 3.11.0
```

Comment: The hashed bundles are there to break browser cache. If they are not working even with that, you must have some other kind of cache layer that is causing that. Also, there is really no trivial to have the UI update on the fly without a browser reload... the only conceivable way I can think of is to have a poller that checks an endpoint and when that endpoint returns the right response (like `/should-update` or something), then you can do a `document.write(...)` with the new index.html you want to show to the client.

Comment: - what is the command you used to build the hash bundles ?

Comment: @RagavanRajan Using angular-cli `ng build --prod --stats-json --base-href=/mywebapp/ --output-path=../serverfolder/mywebapp`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming if you have many environments add the oh flag in all environments

`- ng build --test --no-progress -oh all`

and add it explicitly in production also

You have to use output hashing option to generate the files

so the command will be

`ng build --prod --stats-jason --base-href=/mywebapp/ --output-path=../serverfolder/mywebapp --output-hashing all`

or use the alias (-oh)

`ng build --prod --stats-jason --base-href=/mywebapp/ --output-path=../serverfolder/mywebapp -oh all`

Then use the files from the `dist` folder and check it has unique hashing in all files then host it, please .
Hope it helps

Comment: Hash are unique, when I do `ng build --prod`, by default when you do --prod I believe angular-cli applies --output-hashing=all. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#--dev-vs---prod-builds

Comment: agreed with wiki link.My assumption is when you have more than one environment, if the `-oh all` flag is not added to all environments then you will face this issue. So try to add the `-oh ` flag in all environments and give a try

Comment: I've added output-hashing=all. Unfortunaly i'm getting same results. Client remain on old cache version and the browser does not update.

Comment: In Angular V7- Outuput hashing, bundle optimizations are included in the angular.json file. configurations > production section. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

1. Make sure the bundles that are being created have a unique hash.
2. If they have a unique hash, make sure there is not a secondary cache layer, because unique hashes are cache-busting for browsers, so your case is unusual.

Now, if you want the clients to receive the new updated bundle without reloading the browser, then one way you could achieve that (the only way I can currently think of) is to have either a poller or socket or some sort connected to your server, and when it receives the right response/message, you can do something like a `document.write(...)` with the new `index.html` in the response.

Here is a pseudo-code example:

```
setInterval(() => {
    http.get('/needs-update').subscribe((yes: boolean) => {
        if (yes) {
            http.get('/new-bundle').subscribe((newBundle: string) => {
                document.write(newBundle);
            });
        }
    });
}, 60000);
```

Every minute, it will poll to see if it needs a new bundle. If so, it will get the new bundle.

You can weigh the costs/benefits of the `document.write()` approach, but I think that gives you a general idea of the polling approach.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Not sure why the browser is not updating/refreshing but the hash are unique. Also, Correction on my end. I meant to say that my goal is to update/upload my code and on the client side they should be able to see the reflected changes without having them click reload/refresh button or having a pop-up with click button to reload/refresh your browser.

Comment: I understand. The example code I gave does not show any prompt for the user. It is an automatic background process that will update the users bundle without reloading the page. Read the code and you will see :)

Comment: Ok will do let me give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the basic idea is that the server loads routes based on files, but your whole angular app runs on index.html and it tells the browser which route to show, so with htaccess you pretty much route all server incoming traffic to index.html and it all runs smoothly :)
This is the .htaccess I'm using:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```